# What would happen to the reputation if questions with positive answers are deleted provided that his reputation is too low?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

Suppose, a person has received some reputations by answering some questions. He used those points for bounty for his questions and therefore he loses all his points. Suppose, the questions where he had answers with positive votes are deleted. Then, he should lose those points too. But he had already lost points in Bounty. Then, what would happen?

Comment: @Robert You mean to say that whatever happens, reputation can't go below 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whatever happens the minimum reputation is 1 so if you gain 100 points, give away a 50 rep bounty and then all your positive scoring answers/questions are deleted you'll be on 1 rep.

If you then answered another question and received an upvote you'd be on 11 rep.

Comment: Also, if any of the posts being deleted are older than 60 days and have a score > 3 then they get to keep the rep gained.